# wrong toolbar background (Android)

Tags: toolbar

I use toolbar in my app. It should looks like below:
[image]

But, sometimes, the toolbar background is wrong! I have no idea why this happen...

[image]

Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
......
```

Here's my toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/id_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

Help! Any ideas?

devices:
nexus 5 (4.4.4)
huawei honor 6(4.4.2)

Comment: android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"  instead of this use @color/colorPrimary

Answer (score 0):

Check in your style resource files if you have defined `colorPrimary`.

It's very important to check if in your definition you have something like this `<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/actionbar_solid_background</item>`. This won't work in previous versions of Android (<21) because it targets the native resource of the OS. If that's the case remove `android:` to target the resource used by the support library.

Your style should be something like this.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/actionbar_solid_background</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/actionbar_solid_background</item>
</style>
```